# Как сделать импорт бд в docker-compose контенер?

Tags: docker-compose

имеется docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  web:
    build: ./php
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=#1000
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./migr:/usr/data

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6080:8080
```

В папке migr хранятся 3 sql дампа баз, как их импортировать в базу данных  в контейнере db, при сборке проекта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном *docker-compose.yml* для базы данных используется образ `mariadb`.

На [странице данного образа](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) в разделе *Initializing a fresh instance* сказано что инициализирующие файлы можно поместить в директорию `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` (поддерживаются расширения фалов `.sh`, `.sql`, `.sql.gz`, `.sql.xz` и `.sql.zst`).

Измените строчку монтирования volume `./migr` так, что бы монтирование происходило в `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Таким образом база данных будет инициализироваться содержимым директории `./migr` каждый раз при создании нового контейнера. Т.е. подключить инициализацию, желательно, только один раз, т.к. далее данные уже будут находиться в базе (из-за того что есть монтирование `/var/lib/mysql`), после первой успешной инициализации следует отключить монтирование `./migr` что бы избежать ошибок и потери данных.